# Adding vertical bar to the left of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

Is it possible to add a bar to the left of a UITableViewCell?

I would like to add left bars on selected cells only.

Please check the image below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom TableViewCell

[image]

Create Constraints as Showed

[image]

[image]

constraint View

[image]

set properties to the view on left

[image]

if u get any constraint error u can fix that by adding constraint to leftView, as below

[image]

create outlet for the constraint label to content View

[image]

**This is the main part** above all only to correct the label position

**Objective-C**

In `MyTableViewCell.h` (Custom cell) create outlets

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewOnLeft;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint;////Only if you need to move the label on showing left frame
```

ViewController.m (It contain tableView)

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray* selectedIndexPaths;//Declare Globaly
```

in `viewDidLoad()`

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
[self.tableView allowsMultipleSelection];
self.selectedIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %ld Row %ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row];
if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
{
    [cell.viewOnLeft setHidden:NO];
    cell.leftConstraint.constant = 18; //Only if you need to move the label on showing left frame
}
else
{
    [cell.viewOnLeft setHidden:YES];
    cell.leftConstraint.constant = 3; //Only if you need to move the label on hiding left frame
}
return cell;
```

in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
if ([self.selectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]){
    [self.selectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
}else {
    [self.selectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
}
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

**Swift 4**

In MyTableViewCell.swift (Custom cell) create outlets

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewOnLeft: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

ViewController.swift (It contain tableView)

```
var selectedIndexPaths:[IndexPath]! // Global declaration
```

in `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")//Since i am using xib for custom cell
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
selectedIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
```

in `cellForRowAt indexPath` method

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.label.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"
if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
   cell.viewOnLeft.isHidden = false
   cell.leftConstraint.constant = 18
} else {
   cell.viewOnLeft.isHidden = true
   cell.leftConstraint.constant = 3
}
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.contentView.layoutSubviews()
return cell
```

In `didSelectRowAt indexPath` method

```
if selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
    guard let index = selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) else {
         return
      }
    selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: index)
} else {
    selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
}

tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer thoroughly. I am coding via code though. But I get the idea now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have done it with an additional `UIView` on the `UITableViewCell`. I used it to show a colored bar on the left side of the Row.

I just put a `UIView` onto the `UITableViewCell` in IB, which is a bit shorter than the `UITableViewCell`. Now i just have to change the value for `cell.backgroundcolor` to show a different colored bar on the left side.

Don't forget to change the color of the new `UIView` to the original color of the `UITableViewCell`

//Screenshots are coming soon

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

property of UITableView.

Set Hide Show UIView as vertical Bar in Selection