# How to add vertical bar to UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to add a coloured vertical bar next to each item in a `UITableView` but unsure of the correct and most efficient way to achieve this. Is it possible to reuse the same `UITableViewCell` to colour the bar in differently? as Item D has 3 vertical bars, and Items F & G have 2 vertical coloured bars, would I need to create a different custom `UITableViewCell`? Is it possible to use a rather than a `UIImageView`? It seems very inefficient using an image just for a solid colour. How can this be done programmatically using Swift 4.0? I've already had a look at this:

- [Adding vertical bar to the left of a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310952/adding-vertical-bar-to-the-left-of-a-uitableviewcell)

but this doesn't solve the question.

I'm also looking for the following conditions to be met:

1. Items A, B, C, E & H to have a width of 20 and a height of the  `UITableViewCell`.
2. Item D to have a width of 20 and a height of the `UITableViewCell`. Each coloured vertical bar to be 4 wide, including the white bars in between each coloured one.
3. Items F & G to have a width of 20 and a height of the `UITableViewCell`. Each coloured vertical bar to be 8 wide, leaving 4 in the middle with a white background colour.

**View controller**

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()


    var allItems = ["Item A", "Item B", "Item C", "Item D", "Item E", "Item F", "Item G", "Item H"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Hello World"

        self.tableView.register(CustomCell.self as AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")


        view.addSubview(tableView)

        let constraints = [
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}

extension MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return allItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as? CustomCell

        if cell == nil {
            cell = CustomCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }

        cell?.textLabel?.text = allItems[indexPath.row]

        return cell!
    }
}
```

**Custom UITableViewCell**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    enum BarStyle {
        case single
        case double
        case triple
    }

    var barStyle: BarStyle = .single {
        didSet {
            switch barStyle {
            case .single:
                bar.style = .single
            case .double:
                bar.style = .double
            case .triple:
                bar.style = .triple
            }
        }
    }
    var barColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            bar.color = barColor
        }
    }

    private let bar = VerticalBarView(frame: .zero)

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(bar)
        // setup constraints as needed so bar is positioned and sized properly
        let constraints = [
            VerticalBarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: CustomCell.topAnchor),
            VerticalBarView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: CustomCell.bottomAnchor)
        ]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

**Plist file (Items.plist)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item A</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>single</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>A90F32</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item B</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>single</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>427B7B</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item C</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>single</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>C9910D</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item D</string>
        <key>single</key>
        <string>triple</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>CF009E</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item E</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>single</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>003CA6</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item F</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>double</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>704B1C</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item G</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>double</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>6EC4E8</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Item H</string>
        <key>style</key>
        <string>single</string>
        <key>colour</key>
        <string>95BF32</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

**Extensions.swift**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor {

    static let colorRed = UIColor().colorFromHex("A90F32")
    static let colorTeal = UIColor().colorFromHex("427B7B")
    static let colorGold = UIColor().colorFromHex("C9910D")
    static let colorMagenta = UIColor().colorFromHex("CF009E")
    static let colorNavy = UIColor().colorFromHex("003CA6")
    static let colorBrown = UIColor().colorFromHex("704B1C")
    static let colorLightBlue = UIColor().colorFromHex("6EC4E8")
    static let colorGreen = UIColor().colorFromHex("95BF32")

    func colorFromHex(_ hex : String) -> UIColor {
        var hexString = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

        if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
            hexString.remove(at: hexString.startIndex)
        }

        if hexString.count != 6 {
            return UIColor.black
        }

        var rgb : UInt32 = 0
        Scanner(string: hexString).scanHexInt32(&rgb)

        return UIColor.init(red: CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
                            green: CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
                            blue: CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
                            alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

**Items.swift (contains struct)**

```
import Foundation    

struct mainItem {
    var title: String
    var style: String
    var color: String
}

var itemA = mainItem(title: "Item A", style: "single", color: "A90F32")
var itemB = mainItem(title: "Item B", style: "single", color: "427B7B")
var itemC = mainItem(title: "Item C", style: "single", color: "C9910D")
var itemD = mainItem(title: "Item D", style: "triple", color: "CF009E")
var itemE = mainItem(title: "Item E", style: "single", color: "003CA6")
var itemF = mainItem(title: "Item F", style: "double", color: "704B1C")
var itemG = mainItem(title: "Item G", style: "double", color: "6EC4E8")
var itemH = mainItem(title: "Item H", style: "single", color: "95BF32")
```

**Current result**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

[image]

**rmaddy's suggestion**
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this programmatically? Just add the image view to your `CustomCell` in storyboard, add an outlet to your `CustomCell` class, and update the image to whatever you want in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: Check your plist file. There are a two `style` mistakes.

Comment: Why did you unupvote my answer when you edited your question a short time ago? Why wan't the answer ever accepted? What's missing?

Comment: @rmaddy Your suggestion returns 3 errors. See latest screenshots above. `Value of type 'String' has no member 'title'/'style'/'color'`

Comment: Right. It was expected that you do a little bit of work and not blindly copy and paste everything. And you did keep changing your requirements each time I fleshed out more and more of the answer. I assume the error is from my `cellForRowAt` which is largely left for you to flesh out. The code I put in `cellForRow` is there as a rough guideline for you.

Comment: `cellForRow` or `cellForRowAt`? I didn't just copy & paste everything. I did also make tweaks to try and solve this issue. I did search that error online but didn't find any tutorials let alone working solutions to solve this + Xcode doesn't provide any suggestions to resolve those errors either.

Comment: My `cellForRowAt` is assuming that you have an array of struct as your data model and the struct has title, style, and color properties. My answer hints at this in the text before all of the code. This is where you changed things and added a plist file and all. I left it to you to adapt the large amount of work I put into the answer already to match the data you really have.

Comment: That array of struct I did create - is there something wrong with it? If I don't need a plist file, please let me know. Do you know why those errors appeared in the first place? Why is Swift so annoying?

Comment: It's confusing what you're using the plist file for but I don't see any reason you need it.  Those errors are actually pretty straightforward, you declared `allItems` as an array of strings and not an array of a custom struct type like rmaddy suggested.  I believe your remaining steps should be this: 1) create struct type w/ title, style, color attribute 2) change `allItems` to be array of new struct type and not string 3) populate `allItems` to have the data you defined in the plist but instead created as structs in swift not values in a plist file.

Comment: @MacaronLover Your error indicates that your `allItems` array is an array of `String`, not an array of whatever struct you defined.

Comment: I created a struct in the `Items.swift` file, does that need to be moved to the view controller? The data I created is there but I still trying to figure out how to connect and display it in the table view

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of pieces to this so break it down.

First you need a way to create the vertical bar. You could use images but I would suggest creating a custom `UIView` that defines two properties: The style (solid, two bars, three bars), and the color. Define an `enum` for the style. Implement `draw` to draw the colored bars as needed.

Once you have that custom view working, then implement your `CustomCell` to add an instance of this custom view to left end of its `contentView`. Add properties to the `CustomCell` class for the bar style and color. Setting those properties should update the corresponding properties on the custom bar view.

Update the data model in your table view controller to include the color and style for each row.

Update `cellForRowAt` to set the title, bar style, and bar color of the `CustomCell`.

Here's one way to implement the bar view:

```
class VerticalBarView: UIView {
    enum Style {
        case single
        case double
        case triple
    }

    var style: Style = .single {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    var color = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        (backgroundColor ?? .white).set()
        let bg = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        bg.fill()

        color.set()

        switch style {
        case .single:
            let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
            path.fill()
        case .double:
            let left = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width / 2 - 2, height: bounds.height)
            var right = left
            right.origin.x = right.width + 4
            let pathLeft = UIBezierPath(rect: left)
            pathLeft.fill()
            let pathRight = UIBezierPath(rect: right)
            pathRight.fill()
        case .triple:
            let width = (bounds.width - 8) / 3
            var left: CGFloat = 0
            for _ in 0..<3 {
                let rect = CGRect(x: left, y: 0, width: width, height: bounds.height)
                let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
                path.fill()
                left += width + 4
            }
        }
    }
}

// Test code
let view = VerticalBarView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 44))
view.style = .triple
view.color = UIColor.purple
```

Here is a rough implementation of `CustomCell`:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    enum BarStyle {
        case single
        case double
        case triple
    }

    var barStyle: BarStyle = .single {
        didSet {
            switch barStyle {
            case .single:
                bar.style = .single
            case .double:
                bar.style = .double
            case .triple:
                bar.style = .triple
            }
        }
    }
    var barColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet {
            bar.color = barColor
        }
    }

    private let bar = VerticalBarView(frame: .zero)

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(bar)

        let constraints = [
            bar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
            bar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
            bar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leftAnchor),
            bar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
}
```

Your `cellForRowAt` becomes something like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = allItems[indexPath.row].title
    cell.barStyle = allItems[indexPath.row].style
    cell.barColor = allItems[indexPath.row].color

    return cell
}
```

This last bit of code assumes you've updated your data model to be an array of struct where the struct contains a title, style, and color.

Comment: This is a great example if you don't want to use an image view . Could be really cool if you allow the users to set custom colors.

Comment: @AaronBrager Please notice the `color` property.

Comment: Simple and straightforward solution, kudos. If the style is supposed to be set only in `cellForRow` then the property observers are not necessary.

Comment: @vadian `cellForRowAt` would have no knowledge of `VerticalBarView`. The `CustomCell` would have its own style and color properties which would just delegate to its instance of `VerticalBarView`.

Comment: I was assuming that the view is connected to an outlet in the custom cell and the style is set in `cellForRow` with `cell.verticalBarView.style = ...` but I overlooked that everything is achieved in code.

Comment: @vadian See my update. The idea is that the implementation of the vertical bar is kept "secret" from any user of `CustomCell`.

Comment: @MacaronLover: That's example code - which @rmaddy has done a great job producing. Obviously you would use Autolayout in your app by pinning the top and bottom of the `VerticalBarView` to the top and bottom of your custom cell.

Comment: @RoboticCat I tried updating the `CustomCell` Class but can't apply those constrains for some reason: `Instance member 'topAnchor' cannot be used on type 'VerticalBarView'`

Comment: @MacaronLover I explain it at the end of my answer in the `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: @rmaddy ah okay, but I'm still lost with using constraints to stretch the bar, I added the code to the custom cell class but it's not working :-(

Comment: @MacaronLover See my update for the constraints I think you need.

Comment: @rmaddy I've created an extension (to allow me to use hex colours), a Plist file and an array of struct. Please let me know if I'm on the right track.